# Display a QDialog on mouse over

Tags: c++, qt

I wanted to know how I can display a QDialog on mouse over.
I know how I can setup a context menu but I would like a QDialog on mouse over.

This is what I am doing (which apparently isnt working)

```
void mouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent * event )
{
    QPoint p = this->mapFromGlobal(QPoint(0,0));
    d->move(p); //d is the dailog
    d->show();
}
```

The dialog opens up on the top left corner of the screen. I want it to open up next to the widget that has the mouseMoveEvent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the QDialog elsewhere, and just call show() on it from the mouseMoveEvent() on the QWidget your hovering over

Comment: Thanks. Now how do I make the QDialog popup from a specific location ?

Comment: Take a look at the QWidget documention http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#pos-prop

Comment: You'll probably want the move() function, and set it to be some offset of the current mouse position (via QCursor::pos())

Comment: I am moving the dialog but it still appears on the top left corner of my screen

Comment: where are you moving it to?

Comment: I want the Qdialog to appear next to the widget that has the overriden mouseMoveEvent. Instead the Qdialog appears way off. I want to set the corrdinates of Qdialog

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56224/discussion-between-yankee2905-and-rajeshwar).